# :before content css does not work with Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I used to create space between DIVs, using this css code:

```
.area:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 110px;
}
```

This works on all browsers works except on Safari on Mac.
I tried to change the values ​​of the display or overflow but it does not work.
Can anyone advise me?

Comment: it works fine in safari as well...see this https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/w6tL9d45/

Answer (score 2):

you could simply use `margin-top` on the main element itself:

```
.area {
    margin-top: 110px;
}
```